# How to use \newfam properly?

Tags: math-mode

Consider the following example:

```
\newfam\myfam
\font\myfont=msam10
\textfont\myfam=\myfont
$A\mathchar"2850 B$
\end
```

Notice that family "8" is specified explicitly, because `\mathchar` allows only explicit hexadecimal digits. How to use family allocated by `\newfam`?

Comment: note that `\mathchar` does not require hex, any tex `<number>` is OK, it is conventional to use hex after a `"` but only to make it easier for humans to break up the number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct the number eg:

```
\newfam\myfam
\font\myfont=msam10
\textfont\myfam=\myfont
\def\hex#1{\ifcase#10\or1\or2\or3\or4\or5\or6\or7\or8\or9\or A\or B\or C\or D\or E\or F\fi}

$A\mathchar"2850 B$


$A\mathchar"2\hex\myfam 50 B$
\end
```

Comment: `\numexpr#1\relax` is a safer way to have a number and not add extra space token or expand into the 0 but I stuck to classical plain tex here. The token defined by `\newfam` is always safe in this context.

Comment: I don't understand what is the meaning of "to have a number and not add extra space token or expand into the 0". Please give an example.

Comment: if you try to use this `\hex` with a literal digit instead of `\myfam` then `hex{1}` would  start off `\ifcase10...` and do the wrong thing, you could define it as `\ifcase#1 0\or...`  then `\ifcase{1}` would be `\ifcase1 0\or...` and do the right thing, but `\hex\myfam` would then add a space so you would get `\mathchar"2 850` which would fail again.  `\ifcase\numexpr#1\relax0...` always works but needs etex.